# ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED - SQL SERVER 2008 R2 (GLOBAL)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED for an entire database? Is there any global configuration for this?
Tks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Data may be missing or duplicated in query results with `READ UNCOMMITTED`.

Comment: we have a very old database with performance problems. We made a copy for a test environment, and as a first test we want to change the isolation level to test the performance for a first evaluation

Comment: [`READ UNCOMMITTED/NOLOCK` is not a "go-faster" switch, it's a "return incorrect results switch"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Thank you all. I will change the strategy to analyze the problem